# How does google chrome generates suggestions in address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I type something into the address bar (Omnibox) chrome gives suggestions, but I don't see any network calls. See attached image.


How does Omnibox manage to retrieve suggestions for each input without contacting server?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Notice that the omnibox provide suggestions even without internet connection. So I think he draws them from the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

I think real-time technologies or chrome api's!